# Does dotnet Maui Support Unity Container for Dependency Injection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, unity-container, maui, .net-maui

I am converting my Xamarin Forms Application to dotnetMAUI. In Xamarin I've used Unity Container for dependency injection. Is Unity Container supported in dotnet MAUI?

Comment: Given that it is no longer maintained, if you really want to use it, I recommend downloading the source code, and change it to target .net 6. HOWEVER, Maui comes with Dependency Injection; in the long run it would be more sensible to use that. The various popular DI libraries will also no doubt be updated for Maui, if they have not already been.